# Evaluate a finite sum in a large N limit

Tags: limits, summation

I have a finite sum which I evaluate, and subsequently take a limit to retain only part of the result. I am wondering if it is possible to apply this limit earlier to simplify the finite sum. The motivation is that other similar finite sums are much more difficult to evaluate.

The finite sum is:
$$
1^\intercal \left ( \sum_{i=1}^N A^{i-1} B(N-i) A^{N-i} \right ) \mathbf{v}
$$

where $A,B$ are $2x2$ matrices and $\mathbf{v}^\intercal = (v_1, v_2)$ is some vector. The matrices are:
$$
B(i) = \begin{pmatrix} f_{11}(i) & f_{12}(i) \\ f_{21}(i) & f_{22}(i) \end{pmatrix}
$$

for some arbitrary $f$ (in this case, they happen to be polynomials in $i$). $A$ is some arbitrary constant matrix. We can take the eigendecomposition
$$
A = U D U^{-1} \Rightarrow A^{i-1} = U D^{i-1} U^{-1} \\
\text{where } D = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 \end{pmatrix}
$$

to evaluate the sum.

Now the limit:

Let the larger eigenvalue be $\lambda_2 > \lambda_1$, and as a result for large $N$, terms that are order $\lambda_1^N \rightarrow 0$ (or better: factor out an overall factor of $\lambda_2^N$, and since $\lambda_1/\lambda_2 < 1$ then terms $(\lambda_1/\lambda_2)^N \rightarrow 0$).

The result is some function like $\lambda_2^N ( \dots )$ for some coefficient.

My question is: is it possible to take this $\lambda_1^N \rightarrow 0$ limit **before** evaluating the sum? Or what other strategies exist for evaluating this type of summation in a large $N$ limit?

While this particular sum is possible to evaluate this way, later I am interested in larger sums
$$
1^\intercal \left ( \sum_{i_1=1}^N \sum_{i_2=1}^{N-i_1} \dots \sum_{i_k=1}^{N-i_1-\dots} A^{i_1-1} B(N-i_1) A^{i_2-1} B(N-i_1-i_2) \dots A^{N-i_1-i_2-\dots} \right ) \mathbf{v}
$$

I hope that is not too vague. For those interested, this problem comes from statistical mechanics, for evaluating partition functions.

Thanks for your advice.